# Убрать зависимость от таймера

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Делаю прелоадер страницы:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){     
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      $("#loader").show();
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);    
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){  
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
         $("#loader").hide();
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);      
});
```

Не получается сделать так, чтобы исчезла анимация при полной загрузки `div` `#list`. Работает только с таймером, пробовал через `load`, но тоже не работает.

Comment: а где у вас в коде `#list`?

Comment: сейчас сделано на всю страницу событие,на `#list` не работает